# Can I install the full version of windows 10 from Windows 10 Insider Preview?

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

I want to install Windows 10 (offered for free) on a separate partition (to dual boot), but it is only available for install through windows update if you are running Windows 7 or 8. I can, however, install Windows 10 Insider Preview on a separate partition on my hard drive. If I do this, will I be able to upgrade from the Win 10 Insider Preview to Win 10 (free through windows update)?

Comment: The thing to remember is the free Windows 10 update applies only to Windows 7 and 8. So long as you keep that version installed you can update it, not the insider preview, to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to upgrade. I do not believe it will be free though. The Windows 10 Insider Preview is free, but an upgrade requires a purchase of Windows 7 or 8.1 according to the [FAQs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq). Look under "How do I get my free upgrade?"

EDIT: I just found some more information. It has to be a system with a valid license of 7 or 8.1: [link](https://twitter.com/GabeAul/status/597773851150446592).

Comment: What if I did this:

Create System Image of Windows 7, Copy down product number of Windows 7, Partition the hard drive, Upgrade to windows 10 on current partition, Install windows 7 on second partition to dual boot, Enter product number of Windows 7. Would this make my win 7 key invalid when I try installing win 7 on the second partition?

Comment: If you want to retain your license for Windows 7, make sure to [uninstall the product key](http://www.howtogeek.com/124286/how-to-uninstall-your-windows-product-key-before-you-sell-your-pc/). Then you should be able to install it and use it on another partition.